# Using Go Dep with Private Gitlab repository

Tags: git, go, gitlab

I'm trying to use a private GitLab repository with Go Dep.

Is it possible to use a GitLab Deploy Key to clone the project with Dep?

Below is my sample Gopkg.toml & Deploy Token:

#### Gopkg.toml

```
[[constraint]]
  name = "gitlab.com/example/foo"
  branch = "master"
```

#### Deploy Token:

`Username: gitlab+deploy-token-1234`

`Password: a1234567`

Comment: Yes, it's possible by configuring git (globally or for a single go project only) to fetch data from your custom server instead. I'm using it with gitea, and I haven't had any issues since. Unfortunately, it's not possible with dep only.

Comment: Probably the same as using go tools with other private repos. Have you tried configuring git to use ssh instead of https?

Comment: My question about using `go dep` instead of `go get`.

Comment: Both, `go get` and `dep` just invoke `git`. Duplicate.